# how to read data from excel sheet using jquery?

Tags: jquery, excel

Everything works fine when I have tried with csv files but when I use excel
sheets to read data I don't get data in the proper format. I didn't 
find a correct solution for this. Can any one explain to me the process of reading data from excel sheet using jQuery?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) 
{
    var table = $("<table />");
    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");

    var data = e.target.result;
    var result;

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length-1; i++)// length-1 to g avoid empty csv data
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            var row = $("<thead /> ");
            var cells = rows[i].split(",");
            // console.log(cells);
            for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) 
            {
                var cell = $("<th />");
                cell.html(cells[j]);
                row.append(cell); 
            } 
        } 
        else
        {
            var row = $("<tr />");
            var cells = rows[i].split(",");
            //console.log(cells);
            for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) 
            {
                var cell = $("<td />");
                cell.html(cells[j]);
                if(cells[j]!='')
                    row.append(cell);
            }
        }
        table.append(row);
    }
    $("#id").html('');
    $("#id").append(table);
}
reader.readAsText($("#inputid")[0].files[0]);
```

This code is for csv/txt files. Can any one explain to me the changes needed for excel sheet?

Comment: `.xls` or `.xlsx`?  unpacked or packed?  OpenXML isn't straightforward - you'd be better off using a library (possibly: https://openxmlsdkjs.codeplex.com/) or server-side OpenXML SDK.

Comment: Thankyeww for your response @freedomn..... I got plugin for that                           [link](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls). Its working fine.